# What is the formula of the probability for getting $n$ same adjacent digits in a random hexadecimal number of $r$ digits?

Tags: probability

For example, getting 7d**bbbbb**2-653e-44f1-9b85-bec6ab5a2392 satisfies one of the favorable results, Where n=5 and r=32 is the total number of digits and the base is 16.
Because b repeats 5 times in a row.

Comment: I interpret your question as "getting **exactly**" $n$ same digits ?

Comment: You can get more same digits, but the maximum same digits in a row should be n. Like what are the odds to get n same digits in a row of a random number. Leading zeros allowed.

Comment: Like for decimal 3 digit number we have 10 possibilities of 2 same digits at the beginning multiplied by 9 possibilities of the last digit and 10 possibilities of 2 same digits at the end multiplied by 9 possibilities of the first digit  so it's 180 numbers out of 1000 possibilities which will have 2 same digits in a row.

Comment: If we think of 3 letters word we will have (26 X 25  X 2)/(26^3) = 50/(26*26)= 1/13.52

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I can answer that,

So we have number of total combinations:

16^r.

A specific same digit which appears at the start n times means we are left with

15*16^(r-n-1)

combinations for the rest of the digits.
We have 16 different digits so we need to multiply this number by 16.
Same digit can start in any place until the r-n+1 place. So we need to multiply it by

(r-n+1).

For now we have

16 * (r-n+1) * 15 * 16^(r-n-1) = 15 * (r-n+1) * 16^(r-n).

So final probability equation will be :

[15*(r-n+1)*16^(r-n)]/(16^r)

Substituting with the numbers in the examples, we get 1/37449 odds approximately.
Generalizing it to any base b will give:

[(b-1)*(r-n+1)*b^(r-n)]/(b^r)
This only works for 1 < n < r

Comment: I think there is a small oversight in the part "A specific same digit which appears at the start n times means we are left with "15*16^(r-n-1)". This is true, but then you cannot just multiply it by (r-n+1), because when the digit does not appear at the beginning (or end), then you have an additional constraint: the digit after *and* the digit before must be different. In those case you are left with 15*15*16^(r-n-2) combinations.